# "do they" or "don't they"?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

Which sentence is correct with regard to "do they"/"don't they"?

> It just seems that C++ developers usually don't follow this rule in case of pointers, **do** they?
>
> It just seems that C++ developers usually don't follow this rule in case of pointers, **don't** they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct:

> It just seems that C++ developers usually don't follow this rule in
>   case of pointers, do they?

The rule is: do - don't they; don't - do they. So, you just always use the opposite form.